# Python how to POST already urlencoded form with requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a problem that i cant post something that is already urlencoded

how it should be

```
        dataa = {
        client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGci.....blahblahblah
        }
        r = scraper.post(url,headers=headers, data=dataa)
```

i have tried to make it like

```
"client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&",
```

But it didnt work, any ideas guys?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just discovered & in urldecoded string means new line, i used = as :

```
"client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
```

Hope that will help somebody

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`urllib.parse.unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) to decode data:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

source = "urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGci"
result = unquote(source)
```

If you want to decode dict value dynamically, you can rewrite it:

```
dataa["client_assertion_type"] = unquote(dataa["client_assertion_type"])
```

Comment: I have tried it, but there are things like smthing=smthing&
blah:123

Comment: @Stringsko, what do you mean?

Comment: client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYXV0aC5yaW90Z2FtZXMuY29tXC90b2tlbiIsInN1YiI6ImxvbCIsImlzcyI6ImxvbCIsImV